# Apply mapping to a result in MongoDB to return list of properties, not documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of the following documents:

```
{
    "_id": "id-1"
    "name": "Document 1",
    "movies": [
        {id: 1, score: double, tags: ["A", "B", "C"]},
        {id: 2, score: double, tags: ["A"]},
        {id: 3, score: double, tags: ["B", "C"]},
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "id-2"
    "name": "Document 2",
    "movies": [
        {id: 4, score: double, tags: ["A"},
        {id: 5, score: double, tags: ["B"]},
        {id: 6, score: double, tags: ["C"]},
    ]
},
```

and I'm trying to fetch **movies by tag**. I know how to filter the documents with:

```
db.collection.find( { "movies.tags": "B" } )
```

and I know how to retrieve only the field I'm interested in with a projection as:

```
db.collection.find( { "movies.tags": "B" }, {"movies"} )
```

But I'd like to the result to be a list of movies. Instead, this queries result in a list of Documents matching the query. I expect a way in mongo to do this easily, something like:

```
db.collection.find( { "movies.tags": "B" }, {"movies"} ).aggregation($map: {"movies"})
```

but I can't find it. Resuming, given the collection above I expect the result to be

```
[
   {id: 1, tags: ["A", "B", "C"]},
   {id: 3, tags: ["B", "C"]},
   {id: 5, tags: ["B"]}
]
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually, the document structure is a bit more complex. The `movies` property is currently nested and not in the document root.

If `nestedProperty` is an object, I can use dot notation to reach the tags [as shown here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B97EHkFcski). However, if `nestedProperty` is an array, dot notation doesn't work anymore, [as shown here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7GJS4lSzGJ8).

So again, how can I get to the expected result

```
[
   {id: 1, tags: ["A", "B", "C"]},
   {id: 3, tags: ["B", "C"]},
   {id: 5, tags: ["B"]}
]
```

from the following document structure?

```
[{
    "_id": "id-1",
    "name": "Document 1",
    "otherProperty": [
        {
            "name": "p1",
            "movies": [
                {"id": 1, "score": 1.0, "tags": ["A", "B", "C"]},
                {"id": 2, "score": 1.0, "tags": ["A"]},
                {"id": 3, "score": 1.0, "tags": ["B", "C"]}
            ],
            "text": "some text",
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zxIK9041yIh

Comment: thanks, @chridam, I was actually trying to understand the $unwind documentation. Your example helped understand what I was missing

Comment: @chridam, my example was actually a simplification of the actual document. Your example works fine as long as movies is not nested in another array. I'll update my question to better reflect why the solution doesn't work for the actual real scenario.

Comment: Your revised schema is not valid JSON i.e. `{ "otherProperty": [ "movies": [ ... ] ] }` Perhaps it was a typo and you actually meant `{ "otherProperty":  [  { "movies": [ ... ] } ] }`? If so, does `otherProperty` array only have one element which supposedly is the `{ "movies": [ ... ] }` document or it has multiple documents?

Comment: If `otherProperty` only has one element then the solution is trivial https://mongoplayground.net/p/zYJ5DeYCXB-

Comment: Thank you @chridam. Several typos, in fact. I've updated the last snippet. The thing is my filter's input can't be ```otherProperty.movies.tags```because ```tags```is in an object inside the array. I would need something like ```input: "$otherProperty.movies.$each.tags"``` Hope is clearer now. To answer the question: no, this is a stripped out sample. There are much more properties on it.

Comment: Does this answer the question: https://mongoplayground.net/p/g69--vp9xzh ?